# Calculate Categorical Data as a Percent of Each Category in a Pandas Data Frame Using GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame with the column `COLOR` containing categorical data -

```
  ZIP    YEAR    COLOR
11111    1990        0   
11111    1990        1
11111    2000        1 
11111    2000        1
22222    1990        0
22222    1990        0
22222    2000        0
22222    2000        1
```

How do I aggregate the data by the `ZIP` and `YEAR` columns (`df.groupby(['ZIP', 'YEAR'])`) and calculate the categorical data as a percent of each category such that the result resembles the data frame below?

```
  ZIP    YEAR        COLOR
                  0      1

11111    1990    50     50        
         2000     0    100
22222    1990   100      0         
         2000    50     50
```

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{11111, 1990, 0},
                   {11111, 1990, 1}, 
                   {11111, 2000, 1}, 
                   {11111, 2000, 1}, 
                   {22222, 1990, 0}, 
                   {22222, 1990, 0}, 
                   {22222, 2000, 0}, 
                   {22222, 2000, 1}]
                  , columns=["ZIP", "YEAR", "COLOR"]
                 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df.groupby(["ZIP", "YEAR"])["COLOR"].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).unstack("COLOR").fillna(0)
```

Outputs:

```py
COLOR           0      1
ZIP   YEAR
11111 1990   50.0   50.0
      2000    0.0  100.0
22222 1990  100.0    0.0
      2000   50.0   50.0
```